# Why is operator $p^2$ rotationally invariant in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, rotation

It seems a trivial question but I don't know something explicitly.

We suppose $\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2 m}$ and we have a rotation defined by $\hat{R}_{\mathbf{n}}(\varphi)=\exp \left[-\frac{i \varphi}{\hbar} \mathbf{n} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{L}}\right]$.

It is said the $\hat{H}$ is invariant after rotation.

In my proof, (sorry that I will leave out the hat in the following context)

${p^2}'={R^\dagger}{p^2}{R}=R^\dagger p p R=R^\dagger pRR^\dagger pR=(p')(p')$

because $p'$ changes by a $SO(3)$ group $D$, $p'=Dp $,

I only get ${p^2}'=D p D p $, not a result like ${p^2}'={p^2}$
Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: why did you write $p'^2 = R^\dagger p^2 R$ and not $p'^2 = pR^\dagger R p$?

Comment: Or if we're [pedantic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2899910#comment5989897_2899919), $p\cdot R^\dagger Rp$.

Comment: I might still be a little confused because I want to prove $[H,R]=0$, and it is equal to prove $R^\dagger H R=H$, and equal to prove $R^\dagger p^2 R=p^2$. That is the reason why I let ${p^2}'=R^\dagger p^2 R$. I was trying to make ${p^2}'=p^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my proof, (sorry that I will leave out the hat in the following context)
>
> ${p^2}'={R^\dagger}{p^2}{R}=R^\dagger p p R=R^\dagger pRR^\dagger pR=(p')(p')$

The last term (the far right side) is not really clear. I guess you mean to imply a dot product by writing $(p')(p')$?

If so, with more explicit indices, we have:
$$
p'^2 = \sum_{i}p'_i p'_i = \sum_{i,j}p'_i p'_j \delta_{ij}
$$

> because $p'$ changes by a $SO(3)$ group $D$, $p'=Dp $,

Again, with more explicit indices:
$$
p'_i = \sum_{k=1}^3 D_{ik}p_k\;,
$$
where $D_{ik}$ are components of an element of the defining matrix representation for $SO(3)$. It is a special orthogonal matrix. I.e.,
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^3(D^T)_{k\ell} D_{\ell m} = \delta_{km}
$$

> I only get ${p^2}'=D p D p $, not a result like ${p^2}'={p^2}$
>
> Where do I make a mistake?

Again, with explicit indices:
$$
p'^2 = \sum_{i,j}p'_i p'_j \delta_{ij} = \sum_{i,j,k,\ell} D_{ik}p_k D_{j\ell}p_\ell\delta_{ij}
$$
$$
=\sum_{i,k,\ell} D^T_{ki}D_{i\ell}p_k p_\ell 
$$
$$
=\sum_{k,\ell}\delta_{k\ell}p_k p_\ell= \sum_{k}p_k p_k = p^2
$$